# R: arranging multiple plots together using gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to arrange "plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4" on the same page:

```
library(kohonen) #fitting SOMs

library(ggplot2) #plots

library(GGally) #plots

library(RColorBrewer) #colors, using predefined palettes

 

iris_complete <-iris[complete.cases(iris),] #only complete cases... the iris dataset floats around in the sky with diamonds.

iris_unique <- unique(iris_complete) # Remove duplicates

 

#scale data

iris.sc = scale(iris_unique[, 1:4])

 

#build grid

iris.grid = somgrid(xdim = 10, ydim=10, topo="hexagonal", toroidal = TRUE)

 

# build model

set.seed(33) #for reproducability

iris.som <- som(iris.sc, grid=iris.grid, rlen=700, alpha=c(0.05,0.01), keep.data = TRUE)

 

 

###plots

 

var <- 1 #define the variable to plot

plot1 = plot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)

 

var <- 2 #define the variable to plot

plot2 = plot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)

 

var <- 3 #define the variable to plot

plot3 - plot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)

 

var <- 4 #define the variable to plot

plot4 = plot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)

 

 

 

 

g1 <- grid.arrange(plot1, nrow = 1)

g2 <- grid.arrange(plot2, nrow = 1)

g3 <- grid.arrange(plot3, nrow = 1)

g4 <- grid.arrange(plot4, nrow = 1)

 

grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4, ncol = 1)
```

However, when I use the "grid.arrange()" function, I get an error : `Error in gList - only 'grobs' allowed in gList"`

Right now, I am considering running each of the "plot" statements individually, and manually joining them all using MS Paint. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the approach you are using just add

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

before all four plots.

If you want everything on the same line add instead

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer because of its beautiful simplicity!  Does the par(mfrow=c(2,2)) have to be entered prior to making the plots?

Comment: Yes, before generating the plots. If necessary, you can change the margins.

If you need to generate a single plot later in the script, remember to add `par(mfrow = c(1,1))` to restore the default view!

Comment: I am working on a similar question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798482/labelling-points-on-a-plot-r-language perhaps you could please take a look at it if you have time? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are dealing with the base plot system in R, and assigning the plots to variables does not generate anything (e.g. plot1 is `NULL`). You can use `layout` to split the graphics area into subsections and then plot the individual plots into those:

```r
library(kohonen)
library(RColorBrewer)

iris_unique <- unique(iris[complete.cases(iris),]) # Remove duplicates

#scale data
iris.sc <- scale(iris_unique[, 1:4])

#build grid
iris.grid <- somgrid(xdim = 10, ydim=10, topo="hexagonal", toroidal=TRUE)

# build model
set.seed(33)
iris.som <- som(iris.sc, grid=iris.grid, rlen=700, alpha=c(0.05,0.01), keep.data=TRUE)

### plots
# prepare plot layout
graphics::layout(matrix(seq_len(4), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE), respect=FALSE)

# generate plots
for (var in seq_len(4)){
    plot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], 
         main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I posted a related question here:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798482/labelling-points-on-a-plot-r-language can you please take a look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the package `ggpubr` instead of `grid.arrange`.
I assume you will need to save your plots with `recordPlot()`

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
install.packages("gridGraphics")
library(ggpubr)
library(gridGraphics)

plot1 = recordPlot(iris.som, type = "property", property = getCodes(iris.som)[,var], main=colnames(getCodes(iris.som))[var], palette.name=terrain.colors)

[...]

ggarrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4,ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I posted a related question over here, could you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798482/labelling-points-on-a-plot-r-language thanks!